# Replacing a string but retaining a part of it from a file

Tags: string, replace, sed

I have strings in my files in the format 
`wxT("AnyStringHere")`.

Is it possible to use `sed` in that file to remove the `wxT()` and retain only `"AnyStringHere"`.
Please note that the content inside double quotes keep changing wxT("").
I tried to use regular expression in sed but I am lost. Even if I write a regular expression to match `wxT("AnyStringHere")`, how do I retain the value inside the double quotes.
Any ideas would be very helpful.

For example, if the file has following strings, they should be replaced with the given string.

```
wxT("ThisIsString1") --> "ThisIsString1"
wxT("ThisIsString2") --> "ThisIsString2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
sed  's|wxT(\([^)]*\))|\1|g' file
```

Or

```
sed -r 's|wxT\(([^)]*)\)|\1|g' file
```

To enable inline editing, add `-i`.

```
sed -i 's|wxT(\([^)]*\))|\1|g' file
sed -i -r 's|wxT\(([^)]*)\)|\1|g' file
```

Example input:

```
wxT("ThisIsString1")
wxT("ThisIsString2")
```

Output:

```
"ThisIsString1"
"ThisIsString2"
```

Comment: Wow...this works perfectly. However, it is going to take me some time to understand what exactly is going on in the command (it looks complex) so that next time I can do it myself. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @VikramSingh It's pretty simple. The plain form of the pattern is `wxT([^)]*)` where `[^)]*` matches anything that's not `)`. Since that's the only part we need (`[^)]*`), we enclose it around `()` and use `\1` to represent it but quoting would vary. Without `-r`, `()` must be presented as `\(\)` and literal ones are presented as `()`. With `-r`, the literal ones are the ones presented as `\(\)` whereas `()` is not quoted. I also just chose `|` instead of `/` as the delimiter for `s`.

Comment: Thank you. It is easy to interpret that sed command after reading your explanation.